# Set up anaconda interpreter in PyCharm on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I have anaconda 3 and tensorflow set up and they work well from the anaconda command line. I would like to use PyCharm but cannot add the interpreter Conda.

I followed the instructions from:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

I tried different things. The first is where the conda executable is anaconda.exe:

```
C:\Logiciels\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda.exe create -p     C:\Logiciels\Anaconda3\envs\Ex_Files_TensorFlow -y python=3.7
```

I obtain the error:

```
anaconda: error: argument : invalid choice: 'create' (choose from 'auth', 'label', 'channel', 'config', 'copy', 'download', 'groups', 'login', 'logout', 'move', 'notebook', 'package', 'remove', 'search', 'show', 'upload', 'whoami')
```

I tried the conda.exe as executable:

```
C:\Logiciels\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe create -p C:\Logiciels\Anaconda3\envs\Ex_Files_TensorFlow -y python=3.5
```

But obtain the output:

```
Collecting package metadata: ...working... failed


CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

I also tried:

```
C:\Logiciels\Anaconda3\python.exe create -p C:\Users\hel\.conda\envs\Ex_Files_TensorFlow -y python=3.7
```

The command output is then:

```
C:\Logiciels\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'create': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But the file exists and is there. Why PyCharm doesn't see it?

I also tried version 3.5 instead of 3.7 and a different folder to set the environment in. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Out of the three commands that you have tried, only the conda.exe one is correct. You can setup proxy server in .condarc file if your system is protected by proxy server.

Comment: I don't see how the commands you've listed have anything to do with what it says on the link you mentioned. If you have an existing conda environment, you configure Pycharm with the location of the Python interpreter (`python.exe`) in that environment. That's all. The link doesn't even mention typing any commands.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It is not clear on the help page.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, I looked for existing environement in the conda prompt with the command:

```
conda info --envs
```

that returns environement presents on the machine 
And copy the path to the interpreter field in Add Interpreter >  Conda > Existing Environment > Interpreter

Answer (score 1):

I found my conda.exe buried in folder

> C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts

Comment: It can also be found on a SQL Server under Program Files