# Set up Conda project interpreter in Pycharm on a standalone Windows computer

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, conda

I'm working on Windows 7 standalone computer. I have Anaconda3 (version 4.8.3) installed and Pycharm2020.3.3 as well.

I tried to use [the Anaconda tutorial to configure the Conda environment in PyCharm](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/). But, when I create a new environment, I get an error message:

Executed commands:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe create -p
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my-project-name -y python=3.8
```

Error occurred:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP000 CONNECTION FAILED for URL
<https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
```

Command output:

```
Collecting package metadata: ...working... failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for URL 
<https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
 Elapsed: -An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
 HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

 If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file a support request with 
 your network engineering team.

 'https://repo.anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

I also executed `conda info --envs` (as mention in [that SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56056873/set-up-anaconda-interpreter-in-pycharm-on-windows))

```
base     * C:\ProgramData\Anaconda
```

But I do not know how to proceed from here. What do you offer to do?

Comment: Do you receive the same error on executing listed command in the anaconda prompt?

Comment: indeed, the error on executing the listed command in the anaconda prompt is the same.